# JMeter - [59014] Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: jmeter-5.0

Getting issue in JMeter after trying to record a simple login process.
I dont know how to fix ive googled around and looking for other peoples solution but none so far.

- Jmeter Result Tree:
  Body size in bytes:1123
  Sample Count:1
  Error Count:1
  Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):
  Response code:
  Response message:Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
  **ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**

Certificate:
[The certificate is imported correctly looking at some youtube videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ikI8.png)

Jmeter.log:
2024-03-20 11:37:01,774 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [59007]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '10.8.15.210'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
2024-03-20 11:37:01,906 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.h.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll Socket Factory
2024-03-20 11:37:01,915 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS
2024-03-20 11:37:01,915 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread
2024-03-20 11:37:01,920 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location:  type JKS
2024-03-20 11:37:01,920 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2024-03-20 11:37:01,920 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore
2024-03-20 11:37:01,959 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Add sample Login-415 into controller Login
2024-03-20 11:37:02,214 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [59014]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'passwordsleakcheck-pa.googleapis.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
2024-03-20 11:37:02,365 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Add sample Login-416 into controller Login
2024-03-20 11:37:05,432 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Add sample Login-417 into controller Login
2024-03-20 11:37:05,440 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Add sample Login-418 into controller Login
2024-03-20 11:37:05,446 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Add sample Login-419 into controller Login
2024-03-20 11:37:05,452 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Add sample Login-420 into controller Login
2024-03-20 11:37:05,634 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Add sample Login-423 into controller Login
2024-03-20 11:37:05,651 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Add sample Login-421 into controller Login
2024-03-20 11:37:06,528 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder stopped

Deleted and imported certificate multiple times